# Java Code Style: Positions Inside Class

Tags: java, coding-style

Can you share JLS/JEP or another Oracle/Twitter/Google java code style conventions document where declared positions of class elements.
Like:

```
class Example {
  // public static final variables
  // private static final variables

  // static variables

  // class variables 

  // constructors

  // public methods
  // protected methods

  // inner classes

  // nested classes

  // static methods

  // setter1
  // getter1
  //...
  // setterN
  // getterN

}
```

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: Google provides a wonderful tool for finding this information.

Comment: Here: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.4.2-ordering-class-contents Google wrote that class content ordering is not strongly declared. Is this answer?

Comment: There is no one answer. Various guides will have different rules.

Answer (score 0):

**An excerpt from Google doc:** https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3-source-file-structure

Source file structure

- License or copyright information, if present
- Package statement
- Import statements
- Exactly one top-level class
- Exactly one blank line separates each section that is present.

Each top-level class resides in a source file of its own.
The order you choose for the members and initializers of your class can have a great effect on learnability. However, there's no single correct recipe for how to do it; different classes may order their contents in different ways.

What is important is that each class uses some logical order, which its maintainer could explain if asked. For example, new methods are not just habitually added to the end of the class, as that would yield "chronological by date added" ordering, which is not a logical ordering.

When a class has multiple constructors, or multiple methods with the same name, these appear sequentially, with no other code in between (not even private members).

**From Oracle doc:** Methods should be grouped by functionality rather than by scope or accessibility. For example, a private class method can be in between two public instance methods. The goal is to make reading and understanding the code easier.